# Given a date and time, is there a way to find out what auto-increment id was generated at that time?

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment, rdbms

In a RDBMS, is it possible to get the auto-increment id that would have been generated at a certain date and time?

I need to write a certain range query, and there is an auto-increment primary key that would speed up my query. However, i know only the time range that i am interested in, not the actual primary keys.

So is it possible to:
 Get the auto-increment id generated on date x and date y, and then use that in my query?

Thanks,
Kartik

Comment: @user357065:It will be handy to understand ,if you show some data

Comment: Unless you didn't store that information somewhere, no. You could add a CreationDate field, but you can't rebuild your history. It *may be* possible to revert database to a previous state at a specific date/time, but that would be a cumbersome work to do. Following the question as it may be interesting :)

Comment: if you need to run it once, then just use the dates (who cares if it full scans, just wait).  If for some reason you need to run this over and over for same date range, then maybe: select min(id), max(id) from my_table where my_date_col between dateA and dateB.  Then use those ids for your range query

Answer (score 0):

If you have a create date or update date in the table which uses the sequence you can get that information. In oracle, you can create a trigger to gather this information in a separate table. Other option is to set up MVIEW logging on the target table